# Are user emails returned by Microsoft Graph verified?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Using the Microsoft Graph API, we can get the email address of the logged user using the /me endpoint.

However, is it guaranteed that the returned e-mail address has been verified by Microsoft? (in case where the account has been created with a third party non-outlook email)

Answer (score 1):

The API returns the same emails that you see in the client. The API does no additional sender verification beyond what is already built into Office 365 or Outlook.com.

You can read about unverified senders here: https://learn.microsoft.com/microsoft-365/security/office-365-security/unverified-sender-feature. My quick read of that doesn't see any "guarantee", and indeed it seems to indicate that unverified senders may still show in your inbox (not moved to Junk) in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

The email address comes from the email field in Azure active directory.
This field is usually populated by exchange when the user is provisioned in which case you can consider the email valid. (There are cases where the inbox is going to refuse new mails like when it's full but it is pretty rare).
In the case the user is not populated with an exchange inbox, the administrator can edit that field to provide a value. In which case it is a simple text value and there is no guarantee that it maps to anything functional.

Comment: Thank your your answer! I was more talking about personal Microsoft accounts rather than Entreprise Exchange account , for end-users who register with Microsoft using their own e-mail address rather than creating a new Outlook.com address). It's for a "Sign in with Microsoft" feature for a website. In the old WindowsLive API, there was a verified_email field but not in MS Graph. Is it safe to assume the returned email belongs to the user?

Comment: Use case: A user creates an account regularly on my website, with its e-mail. If later he chooses to use Microsoft to sign-in and there is a match with the e-mail address returned by MS Graph and an account in my database, can I safely login my user using its existing account? (= Am I sure that the e-mail associated with his MS account has been verified, if it's a third-party email, like gmail,...)

Comment: A "live accounts" either maps to a Outlook inbox (consumer version) or to a third party mailbox. I'm pretty sure people get an email verification for a third party inbox. I'm not sure what happens if they ignore it though or the address is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Users from enterprise tenants can have an unverified email address in the email field returned by Microsoft's Graph API.

Normal Microsoft accounts, however, are only able to authenticate your application, if they have a verified primary email address.

Therefore, it's safe to say that the email was verified by the user, as long as you enforce the 'consumers' tenant field, when authenticating new users.